# Reduce algorithm into some Linq expressions for performance reasons to particular structure

Tags: c#, linq

hello I want to see if there is the chance to make a linq expression to help me with performance:
I get a list `List<ContentPage> contentPages` :

```
public class ContentPage : IDateSortableContentItem
{
    [DataMember]
    public ContentPageType PageType { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string CultureID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string PageName { get; set; }}
```

Now this is what I do but takes too long:

```
    private List<ContentPageViewModel> ConvertContentPagesToContentPageViewModels(List<ContentPage> contentPages)
{
  List<ContentPageViewModel> contentPageViewModels = new List<ContentPageViewModel>();
  foreach (var contentPage in contentPages)
  {
    // Check that the list to return does not have the value to be currently used
    if (!contentPageViewModels.Any(p => p.PageName.ToLower() == contentPage.PageName.ToLower()))
    {
      // Grab all the objects with the same name
      var contentForms = contentPages.Where(p => p.PageName.ToLower() == contentPage.PageName.ToLower()).ToList();
      List<CultureContentPageData> cultureContentPageDatas = new List<CultureContentPageData>();

      // Iterate through the pages with the same name but different cultures
      foreach (var contentForm in contentForms)
      {
        string pageStatus = string.Empty;
        if (contentForm.BeginTime < DateTime.UtcNow && contentForm.EndTime > DateTime.UtcNow) {
          pageStatus = "Active";
        } else if (contentForm.BeginTime > DateTime.UtcNow) {
          pageStatus = "Future";
        } else if (contentForm.EndTime < DateTime.UtcNow) {
          pageStatus = "Inactive";
        } else {
          pageStatus = "Unknown";
        }

        cultureContentPageDatas.Add(
         new CultureContentPageData()
         {
           Culture = contentForm.CultureID.Trim(),
           MinBeginDate = contentForm.BeginTime.ToString(),
           MaxEndDate = contentForm.EndTime.ToString(),
           ActiveStatus = pageStatus
         });
      }
        // Add to main list
      contentPageViewModels.Add(new ContentPageViewModel()
      {
        PageName = contentPage.PageName,
        PageType = contentPage.PageType,
        PreviewUrl = GetPreviewUrl(contentPage.PageName, contentPage.PageType),
        CultureContentPages = cultureContentPageDatas.OrderBy(c => _culturesByCountry.IndexOf(c.Culture)).ToList()
    });
    }
  }
  return contentPageViewModels;
}
```

eventually the data in the front end looks like this:

[image]

but the closer I have gotten to make it into a ContentPageViewModel list is this linq expression

```
var groupContentPages = contentPages.GroupBy(p => p.PageName.ToLower()).Select(grp => grp.ToList()).ToList();
```

and it brings this List within a List like this but not close enough:

[image]

Any pointer or help with be greatly appreciated I have worked this for weeks now, thank you

Comment: Please post your code as text, not images.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code. Post your actual code.

Comment: Like the other said, dont post screenshots. Also it will help your chance of getting answers if the code you post is the one relevant for your question and not a lot of other properties that doesnt affect your problem.

Comment: My apologies thank you for the feedback I just changed it

Comment: I would expect `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(string, string)` to be faster (or, certainly, produce no intermediate `string`s) compared to `==` with `ToLower()` called on both operands.  `contentPageViewModels.Any()` could be replaced by a `HashSet<>` or `Dictionary<>` if it's a lengthy collection.

Comment: `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(string, string)` did help a bit with performance

Comment: I would be bit cautious about using `ToLowerInvariant` or `OrginalIgnoreCase` when you are dealing with possibly international languages - is it known that your page names are only basic Latin characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, in general LINQ to Objects is not going to be faster than `foreach` or even nested `foreach`, though your logic could be improved to using `GroupBy` to not exponentially collect the `contentForms`. Second, I am not sure in this case LINQ is an improvement in readability or understandability over what you had. Thirdly, your logic has a bit of a hole in the `ActiveStatus` computation - if `UtcNow` happens to equal `BeginTime`, you return `Unknown` - shouldn't that be `Active`?

In any case, here is the LINQ to objects version of your method:

```
private List<ContentPageViewModel> ConvertContentPagesToContentPageViewModels(List<ContentPage> contentPages) {
    var UtcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var contentPageViewModels =
        (from p in contentPages
         group p by p.PageName.ToLowerInvariant() into contentForms
         let contentPage = contentForms.First()
         select new ContentPageViewModel() {
             PageName = contentForms.First().PageName,
             PageType = contentForms.First().PageType,
             PreviewUrl = GetPreviewUrl(contentForms.First().PageName, contentForms.First().PageType),
             CultureContentPages =
                contentForms.Select(contentForm => new CultureContentPageData() {
                    Culture = contentForm.CultureID.Trim(),
                    MinBeginDate = contentForm.BeginTime.ToString(),
                    MaxEndDate = contentForm.EndTime.ToString(),
                    ActiveStatus = (contentForm.BeginTime < UtcNow && UtcNow <= contentForm.EndTime)
                                        ? "Active"
                                        : (contentForm.BeginTime > UtcNow)
                                            ? "Future"
                                            : (UtcNow >= contentForm.EndTime)
                                                ? "Inactive"
                                                : "Unknown"
                })
                .OrderBy(c => _culturesByCountry.IndexOf(c.Culture))
                .ToList()
         })
         .ToList();

    return contentPageViewModels;
}
```

And here is my recommended version:

```
private List<ContentPageViewModel> ConvertContentPagesToContentPageViewModels(List<ContentPage> contentPages) {
    var UtcNow = DateTime.UtcNow; // make the answer consistent
    var contentPageViewModels = new List<ContentPageViewModel>();

    foreach (var contentForms in contentPages.OrderBy(p => _culturesByCountry.IndexOf(p.CultureID.Trim())).GroupBy(p => p.PageName.ToLowerInvariant())) {
        var cultureContentPageDatas = new List<CultureContentPageData>(contentForms.Count());

        // Iterate through the pages with the same name but different cultures
        foreach (var contentForm in contentForms) {
            string pageStatus;
            if (contentForm.BeginTime < UtcNow && UtcNow <= contentForm.EndTime)
                pageStatus = "Active";
            else if (contentForm.BeginTime > UtcNow)
                pageStatus = "Future";
            else if (UtcNow >= contentForm.EndTime)
                pageStatus = "Inactive";
            else
                pageStatus = "Unknown";

            cultureContentPageDatas.Add(
             new CultureContentPageData() {
                 Culture = contentForm.CultureID.Trim(),
                 MinBeginDate = contentForm.BeginTime.ToString(),
                 MaxEndDate = contentForm.EndTime.ToString(),
                 ActiveStatus = pageStatus
             });
        }

        // Add to main list
        var contentPage = contentForms.First();
        contentPageViewModels.Add(new ContentPageViewModel() {
            PageName = contentPage.PageName,
            PageType = contentPage.PageType,
            PreviewUrl = GetPreviewUrl(contentPage.PageName, contentPage.PageType),
            CultureContentPages = cultureContentPageDatas
        });
    }
    return contentPageViewModels;
}
```